# Как получить параметры `post` запроса `xhr` в puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Как получить параметры `post` запроса `xhr`, который выполняется после загрузки главной страницы?

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Comment: https://pptr.dev/guides/request-interception/